# How to shift an image on a Bootstrap Carousel

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

working with a simple bootstrap Carousel for a class assignment.  I've reduced the max-height of the images to 400px but as a result the top of the images are the only things being displayed.  I've tried messing with the margins a bit on the image and was about to just crop the images so they fit but I figured I'd ask the community first.

How does one recalibrate where the images on a boostrap decide to center the image?  I just want to shit the image up so the middle of the image is what is being displayed on the now resized carousel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you maybe be looking for the `object-fit: contain` css property
When specified an image will be show at is maximum size that still mantains
aspect ratio.

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp

```
.carousel-item {
  max-height: 200px;  
}

.carousel-item img {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

Comment: If it worked for you, please take a second to mark the question as answered